# asp.net mvc2 select value from database according to listbox value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am using asp.net mvc2.I have a listbox and textbox when i select an item from listbox corresponding value to that item should appear in textbox from database.please help

Comment: what did you try so far? how do you load the data from the database? Share some code please!

Comment: i don't have any code.my requirement is like this eg: i have machine name in listbox when i select one item price of that machine come in textbox..how its is done in mvc2 asp.net

Answer (score 1):

You should use JavaScript for handle listbox selection changes.

And read about Ajax, it neads to get the data from DB without reloadin page.

**Add**

Example how can you handle listbox selection changes.

```
@Html.ListBox("nam",new SelectList(new string[]{"opt1","opt2"}),new {onchange = "javaScript:actch()", id = "namid"})
<script type="text/javascript">
    function actch() {
        alert(document.getElementById("namid").value);
    }
</script>
```

Value "document.getElementById("namid").value" contains option that you select.

You should send this value to the server and recieve request

```
@Html.ListBox("nam",new SelectList(new string[]{"opt1","opt2"}),new {onchange = "javaScript:actch()", id = "namid"})
<script type="text/javascript">
    function actch() {
                 $.ajax({
                      url: "your url",
                      type: "POST",
                      data: "id = " + document.getElementById("namid").value,
                      success: function (data) {
                           // action on success  

                           document.getElementById("TextBoxId").value = data;              
                      },
                      error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                           // action on fail                              
                      },
                      complete: function () {

                      }
                  });
    }
</script>
```

You have to write a server request part, and configure ajax.
(I had use jQuery)

**Added:** Server request part (example)

```
    [HttpPost]
    public MvcHtmlString Detail(string id)
    {
        var d = _db.GetVehicle(Convert.ToInt32(id));
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Type: {0}</br>", d.Type));
        sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Brand: {0}</br>", d.Brand));
        sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Model: {0}</br>", d.Model));
        sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Number: {0}</br>", d.Number));
        sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Year: {0}</br>", d.Year));
        sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Cost: {0}</br>", d.Cost));
        return new MvcHtmlString(sb.ToString());
    }
```

URL looks like: MyController/Detail/

DATA for ajax: "id=" + document.getElementById("namid").value

P.S. Some one edit/spoil my ansver and it's not marked(

Comment: can any one give the server request part of the same

Comment: It depends from your database, business logic. Wait five minutes I place some example. Only the one who can write this part)

Comment: It most bigous answer that I ever write. You MUST check this answer as answer)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague but this is basically how it can be done:

You can post the value of the listbox in the change event by using jquery (or any other JS library of your preference). Then the controller gives a value back, which you then put in the textbox.

Check out http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/